# Ajax отправка запроса

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Здравствуйте, как можно реализовать, что бы при загрузке сразу отправлялся запрос, а далее по нажатию кнопки, спасибо

html

```
<div id="my">
    <a href="#" name="button1" class="button1 clet">кнопка</a>
    <a href="#" name="button2" class="button2 clet">кнопка</a>
    <a href="#" name="button3" class="button3 clet">кнопка</a>
    <a href="#" name="button4" class="button4 clet">кнопка</a>
</div>
<span id="results"></span>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){                       
  $('#my').on('click', '.clet', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id : $(this).data('num')},
        url: 'index.php',
        success: function(jsondata){
            $('.button1').html(jsondata.name1);
            $('.button2').html(jsondata.name2);
            $('.button3').html(jsondata.name3);
            $('.button4').html(jsondata.name4);
            $('.button1').attr('data-num', jsondata.num1); 
            $('.button2').attr('data-num', jsondata.num2); 
            $('.button3').attr('data-num', jsondata.num3); 
            $('.button4').attr('data-num', jsondata.num4); 
            $('#results').html(jsondata.error);
        }
    });          
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно занести `ajax` запрос отдельно в функцию вот так

```
function ajaxRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id : $(this).data('num')},
        url: 'index.php',
        success: function(jsondata){
            $('.button1').html(jsondata.name1);
            $('.button2').html(jsondata.name2);
            $('.button3').html(jsondata.name3);
            $('.button4').html(jsondata.name4);
            $('.button1').attr('data-num', jsondata.num1); 
            $('.button2').attr('data-num', jsondata.num2); 
            $('.button3').attr('data-num', jsondata.num3); 
            $('.button4').attr('data-num', jsondata.num4); 
            $('#results').html(jsondata.error);
        }
    });    
}
```

И вызвать там, где надо:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                       
      $('#my').on('click', '.clet', function() {
          ajaxRequest();
      })
    });

    ajaxRequest();
</script>
```

Так как присутствует внутри `$(this).data('num')` то функцию надо сделать принимающей на вход 1 параметр, допустим `num`. При этом при загрузке странице определить какое-то дефолтное значение. в итоге общий `javascript` код будет таким:

```
var DEFAULT_NUM = 999;  

$(document).ready(function(){                       
  $('#my').on('click', '.clet', function() {
      ajaxRequest($(this).data('num'));
  })
});

ajaxRequest(DEFAULT_NUM);


function ajaxRequest(num) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id : num},
        url: 'index.php',
        success: function(jsondata){
            $('.button1').html(jsondata.name1);
            $('.button2').html(jsondata.name2);
            $('.button3').html(jsondata.name3);
            $('.button4').html(jsondata.name4);
            $('.button1').attr('data-num', jsondata.num1); 
            $('.button2').attr('data-num', jsondata.num2); 
            $('.button3').attr('data-num', jsondata.num3); 
            $('.button4').attr('data-num', jsondata.num4); 
            $('#results').html(jsondata.error);
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: только с `$(this).data('num')` надо что-то сделать

Comment: есть предложения?

Comment: Сделать дефолтный `data-num`. например. `DATA_NUM_DEFAULT = 1` и делать проверку, что-то типа `data: { id : $(this).data('num') || DATA_NUM_DEFAULT }` Соответственно если неопределен будет `$(this).data('num') ` будет браться дефолтное значение

Comment: А можно вообще сделать так `$(".clet").first().click();` при загрузке. Если это конечно не плохо)) А то фиг потом вспомнишь зачем это надо)

Comment: Все работает отлично, а вот с data('num'), вообще беда или отправляет постоянно 1, или ничего не отправляет

Comment: @РоманФедоров Подправил ответ для полного понимания как это будет выглядеть.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо Вам большое!